# Is there a way to solve apns invalid request ID issue?

Tags: django-rest-framework, push-notification

I use an ios application whose admin part is built in django/python.
Everything was working fine until mid 2022, we encountered a problem with the expired certificate, this certificate has been renewed but since then when you install the app on an iPad it's going well but when you connect (id + password password) things don't go as planned. The app remains blocked and the server side logs record the message below:

```
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): POST /api/apns/update/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in [getline-blocking] 0 readbytes
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): 34 bytes
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): Host: django.example.com\r\n

[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): {"registration_id":"{length=32,bytes=0x5124a3ee7b3a9b3afa63db66c63df4b8...0a5253c7e9fc0144}"}
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): 258 bytes
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nDate: Thu, 23 apr 2023 09:46:27 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5\r\nVary: Accept\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nAllow: POST, OPTIONS\r\nContent-Length: 37\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): 37 bytes
[dumpio:trace7] [pid 10033] mod_dumpio.c(103): [client ] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-HEAP): {"message":"Invalid registration_id"}
```

I'm trying to figure out where the problem is coming from. Old ipad ipads work correctly, the problem only occurs after new tablets (if you reinstall on an old tablet no problem, but if new tablet or reset problem).

I'm thinking of a certificate problem, I created a new one but the problem persists. Is the problem with django push notification? I don't know but at this point I have a thousand and one questions, I'm stuck and I need your help.

```
@api_view(['POST',])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def createAPNSDevice(request):
    try:
        device = APNSDevice.objects.get(registration_id=request.data["registration_id"])
    except:
        apns = APNSDeviceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not apns.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response({"message": "Invalid data",}, status=400)
        apns.save()
    return Response({"message": "APNS device created",}, status=200)


@api_view(['POST',])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def updateAPNSDevice(request):
    try:
        apns = APNSDevice.objects.get(registration_id=request.data["registration_id"])
        apns.user = request.user
        apns.save()
    except:
        return Response({"message": "Invalid registration_id", }, status=400)
    return Response({"message": "APNS device updated",}, status=200)
```

```
Django settings for inspectionsBO project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'something'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["django.example.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'core',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'admin_reorder',
    'push_notifications',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'passwrd',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-EN'


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

BASE_SERVER_URL = 'http://django.example.com'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/images/")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
IMAGES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/images/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
}


EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_HOST = 'ip adress'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxx'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': BASE_DIR + '/Log/info.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'simple',
        },
        'import': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': BASE_DIR + '/Log/import.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'loggers': {
        'sample': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'import': {
            'handlers': ['import'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
        "APNS_CERTIFICATE": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/apns-prod-cert.pem"),
        "APNS_HOST": "gateway.push.apple.com",
        "APNS_FEEDBACK_HOST": "feedback.push.apple.com",
}
```

Thank you